# create data.fame satisfying some condition

Tags: r, dataframe

#### Input

```
final_table =
  Chr     start       end   num seg.mean seg.mean.1 seg.mean.2
    1  68580000  68640000 A8430   0.7000     0.1440     0.1032
    1 115900000 116260000 B8430   0.0039     2.7202     2.7202
    1 173500000 173680000    C5  -1.7738    -0.0746    -0.2722
```

How can I make a new data.frame where the values of columns 5 through 7 are set to:

-1, if value < -0.679

0, if -0.679 <= value <= 0.450

+1, if value > 0.450

#### Expected output

```
Chr     start       end   num seg.mean seg.mean.1 seg.mean.2
  1  68580000  68640000 A8430        1          0          0
  1 115900000 116260000 B8430        0          1          1
  1 173500000 173680000    C5       -1          0          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
# read the data in
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Chr     start       end        num    seg.mean    seg.mean.1   seg.mean.2
1   68580000    68640000    A8430    0.7000      0.1440     0.1032 
1   115900000   116260000   B8430    0.0039      2.7202     2.7202
1   173500000   173680000   C5      -1.7738      -0.0746    -0.2722")

# get the column-names of the columns you wanna change
cols <- names(df[5:length(df)])
# set a function for the different values you want for the value-ranges
fun_cond <- function(x) {
    ifelse(x < -0.679 , -1, ifelse(
    x >= -0.679 & x <= 0.450, 0, 1))
}
# copy the data-frame so the old one doesnt get overwritten
new_df <- df

# work with data-table to apply the function to the columns
library(data.table)
setDT(new_df)[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, fun_cond), .SDcols = cols]
```

output:

```
   Chr     start       end   num seg.mean seg.mean.1 seg.mean.2
1:   1  68580000  68640000 A8430        1          0          0
2:   1 115900000 116260000 B8430        0          1          1
3:   1 173500000 173680000    C5       -1          0          0
```

same thing without using any additional packages:

```
cols <- names(df[5:length(df)])
fun_cond <- function(x) {
    ifelse(x < -0.679 , -1, ifelse(
        x >= -0.679 & x <= 0.450, 0, 1))
}

new_df <- df
new_df[5:length(df)] <- lapply(new_df[5:length(df)], fun_cond)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the cut function and apply it to the last three columns individually.
  Here's a simple example:

```
original = data.frame(a=c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 2)), seg.mean=c(-1, 0, 0.4, 0.5));
original$segmented = cut(original$seg.mean, c(-Inf, -0.679, 0.450, Inf), labels = c(-1,0,1))
```

One thing to be careful about: the new column will be a factor. If you need numerical values, you may need to apply as.numeric to it.

You can also try to use labels=FALSE which will give you numerical values (but likely 1,2,3 rather than -1,0,1). You can fix that by subtracting 2:

```
original$segmented = cut(original$seg.mean, c(-Inf, -0.679, 0.450, Inf), labels = FALSE)-2
```

Comment: I would apply your cut-function using lapply, so doing something like: `lapply(original[5:length(df)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character((cut(x,c(-Inf, -0.679, 0.450, Inf), labels = c(-1,0,1)))`

Comment: great answer @gvrocha. I did a nested ifelse. I like this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly replace fields in the data frame by subsetting

```
df[, 5:7] <- ifelse(df[, 5:7] < -0.679, -1,
             ifelse(df[, 5:7] < 0.450, 0,
             1))
```